# Как разделить строку на название и версию?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста с тем что я вообще не понимаю :(
Из таких строк:

- `CraftBukkit on Bukkit 1.4.7-R1.1-SNAPSHOT: AntiInvisible 0.9`
- `Dclear 2.0`
- `PVPGamemode 1.0`
- `WorldEdit 5.5.2-SNAPSHOT`

Разделить типо так:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => CraftBukkit on Bukkit
        [1] => 1.4.7-R1.1-SNAPSHOT: AntiInvisible 0.9
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Dclear
        [1] => 2.0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => PVPGamemode
        [1] => 1.0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => WorldEdit
        [1] => 5.5.2-SNAPSHOT
    )
```

Смысл в том чтобы разделить название и версию, как видно версия всегда начинается с цифр.

Answer (score 2):

```
split ('[0-9]', 'строка',2);
```

тогда правим на

```
preg_split('[[:digit:]]', 'строка',2);
```

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.
печаль :(

Comment: а много нада так строк отформатировать?

Comment: ну там обычно от одного до 100 где то

Comment: а ну тогда норма - исправленный вариант  работает?

Comment: к сожалению чет не пашет, вот работает вроде не плохо то что выше Fike предложил, но не получается массив прогнать через foreach. обрабатывает только первую строку :(

Comment: а как работает? в чем не пашет то?

Comment: @Ale_x С версии PHP 5.3.0 эта функция считается УСТАРЕВШЕЙ. Крайне не рекомендуется полагаться на эту возможность. (split)

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать отдельную строку, для каждой строчки такую регулярку

```
([^\d]*)(.*)
```

Не проверял работает или нет, но попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Если только на две строчки:

```
$str = 'Version splitter 2.0-RC';
$pattern = '-^(\w+[\s\w]*)\s+(\d.*)$-';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // [1] - название, [2] - версия
```

Думаю, правда, что этим не обойдется (

Comment: не обошлось:((( как массив через foreach прогнать? что то только первую строку обрабатывает :(

Comment: Странный вопрос...

    foreach ($array_of_strings as $key=>$str) {
        preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
        var_dump($matches);
    }

[man][1]

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: А регулярку я бы поправил как-то так:

    $pattern = '/^((?:\D|\S\d)+)\s(\d.+)$/'

Comment: Спасибо большое, всю ночь сидел и не понимал почему через foreach обрабатывает только первую строку, а все дело было в регулярке.